# Extracting cookies from cookie_jar by cookie name

Tags: perl, www-mechanize, lwp-useragent

What I'm struggling with is why LWP::UserAgent doesn't provide an accessor so that I can just get everything I want to know about a cookie in the cookie_jar by providing the cookie's name.  I realize there is the scan() method on cookie_jar, but it seems like a lot of overhead to provide a callback for something so basic.  This is what I have right now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump qw (dump);
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;
$mech->get( 'http://www.nytimes.com' );

my %cookies = (); 
$mech->cookie_jar->scan( \&check_cookies );

dump \%cookies;

sub check_cookies {
    my @args = @_; 
    $cookies{ $args[1] } = { 
        version   => $args[0],
        val       => $args[2],
        path      => $args[3],
        domain    => $args[4],
        port      => $args[5],
        path_spec => $args[6],
        secure    => $args[7],
        expires   => $args[8],
        discard   => $args[9],
        hash      => $args[10],
    };  
}
```

The output of the script is something like this:

```
{   adxcs => {
        discard   => 1,
        domain    => ".nytimes.com",
        expires   => undef,
        hash      => {},
        path      => "/", 
        path_spec => 1,
        port      => undef,
        secure    => undef,
        val       => "-", 
        version   => 0,
    },       
    RMID => {
        discard   => undef,
        domain    => ".nytimes.com",
        expires   => 1374340257,
        hash      => {},
        path      => "/", 
        path_spec => 1,
        port      => undef,
        secure    => undef,
        val       => "02b4bc821c00500991212ba2",
        version   => 0,
    },       
}
```

So, that gives me easy access to a cookie by name, but I was wondering if there's an easier way to do this or if there's a helpful module I just don't know about.

Comment: I should say that, having delved into this a bit deeper, my question and sample code are quite naive.  Storing all cookies in the cookie jar based solely on their name works fine if all of the cookies in your cookie jar are from exactly the same domain.  Otherwise, it breaks down and is kind of pointless.  Having said that, I would like to see a module which returns cookie objects which you can then update and set.  I'm currently working on this code and hope to publish it to CPAN shortly.

Comment: I've now posted the code to https://metacpan.org/module/HTTP::CookieMonster

Comment: I realise this has been a long time since your original post, but the perl modules [Cookie](https://metacpan.org/pod/Cookie) and [Cookie::Jar](https://metacpan.org/pod/Cookie::Jar) do what you want and more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$cookies->scan(sub  
{ 
  if ($_[1] eq $name) 
  { 
    print "$_[1] @ $_[4] = $_[2]\n"; 
  }; 
});
```

Output would be for example:

```
sessionID @ www.nytimes.com = 1234567890
```

---

**Edit:** >>

```
sub getCookieValue
{
  my $cookies = $_[0];
  my $name = $_[1];
  my $result = null;
  $cookies->scan(sub  
  {  
    if ($_[1] eq $name) 
    { 
      $result = $_[2];
    }; 
  });
  return $result;
}
```

and use it like so:

```
print getCookieValue($cokies, 'sessionID');
```

Comment: Well, that's essentially what my code is already doing, but it has the added layer of creating a hash I can access. What I'd like to do is pass a cookie name to a method and get something in return.  As far as I can tell, scan doesn't return anything, so it's useful for debugging in that context, but not for returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

It has been some time since the OP question, post, but the perl modules [Cookie](https://metacpan.org/pod/Cookie) and [Cookie::Jar](https://metacpan.org/pod/Cookie::Jar) do what the OP wants and more.

Comment: Unrelated to this, would you be able to review your pull request https://github.com/libwww-perl/URI/pull/96 to see if you'd like to address any of the comments? We're at the Perl Toolchain Summit right now looking at it.